Prove that $BD{\parallel }MN$.
In the figure below, $BC=CD$ and points $A$ and $P$ are arbitrary points on the circle.
Prove that $BD{\parallel }MN$.
So far, I tried to compare all equal arcs and subtended angles and also tried and found some similar triangles in order to some how prove that $BD{\parallel }MN$ but to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated!


How is $A$ defined? Or is it arbitrary? You need to be more specific about the problem.

"Similar triangles" works. The idea is to find the height of $M$ above/below $BD$ and/or the tangent to $C$, and show that is equal to the height of $N$. $\quad$ And of course, coordinate geom brute force works.

Because $BC=CD$ the angles subtended at $P$ and $A$ are equal, I marked them with $\alpha$. But that means they lie not only on circle $BCDAP$ but also on circle $PANM$. Hence $\angle{MNP}=\angle{MAP}=\angle{BAP}=\angle{BDP}$, where I marked the $\beta$s. So $PD$ is a traversal of two parallel lines $MN,BD$.

EDIT: The key to finding this solution is to ask: "what happens when two arbitrary points are placed on the circle with two congruent chords?" The answer is that congruent arcs are cut, and the points will subtend equal arcs and angles if they are joined to those chords. Which makes them good candidates for cyclic relations beyond those of the original circle. By the way that $M,N$ are defined in this post - as the intersections of those very chords that join the points to the congruent chords - we inherently have a second cyclic relationship of $APNM$, which quickly leads to the proof that $NM \parallel CD$. Because the points $A,P$ are supposed to be arbitrary, I chose an initial configuration that seemed (to me) to illustrate the argument well, which applies in all configurations of points, just with consideration of supplemental angles too when the points lie on the minor arcs behind the congruent chords. My diagram led to some confusion because it wasn't the OP diagram. The OP diagram, probably by design (if in a book), was meant to mildly disguise the solution by putting the point $P$ in such a minor arc. Below is the marked up OP diagram showing the adjustments needed for this configuration:
As before, $\angle{CAB},\angle{CAD},\angle{CPD}=\alpha$. Further, and this is the adjustment for $P$ lying on a minor arc: $\angle{MPD}=(180-\alpha)=\alpha'$, so we have points $A,P$ subtending angles $\alpha, (180-\alpha)$ on segment $MN$, indicating $APNM$ is cyclic, which I marked with a red dashed circle. Now just follow the sequence of angles marked $\beta_1-\beta_4$ as in the first proof.


Sparrow, You have altered the diagram and that has confused me, since in my diagram $M$ is outside the circle but in yours $M$ is inside the circle. And also how do you know that those four red points are on that red circle? Could you please use the original diagram?

I understand that and I'll try to orient myself to your diagram, but still don't know why those 4 red points are on that red circle. Could you please elaborate it for me?

@RobinSparrow, In $OP's$ diagram how do you prove that points $A,N,P,M$ are concyclic?

@RobinSparrow, Excellent.

Thank you very much.

(Completing via OP's idea of similar triangles. We have the obvious ones arising from Power of a Point.)
Let the tangent at $C$ be the x-axis.
Let the height of $A, B, C, D, P, N, M$ be represented by $a, b, c, d, p, n, m$ respectively.
Since $BD$ is parallel to the x-axis, hence $b = d$.
By considering similar triangles $MPB, MAC$: $ \frac{ m-p}{m-b} = \frac{m-a}{m-c}$.
By considering similar triangles $NPC, NAD$: $ \frac{n-p}{n-d} = \frac {n- a} { n-c}$
There is a unique solution to $ (x-p)(x-c) = (x-a)(x-b)$, namely given by $ x^* = \frac{ ab-pc}{ a+b-p-c}$.
Thus, $ m = x^* = n$ and so $MN$ is parallel to the x-axis.

This follows directly from Pascal's theorem for degenerated hexagon $ABDPCC$.
